# How to find the common denominator of an element of the web?

Tags: website, developer-tools, ublock-origin

From [uBlock Origin: how to remove any element from a page permanently - gHacks Tech News](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/02/21/ublock-origin-how-to-remove-any-element-from-a-page-permanently/)

> Some sites use dynamic identifiers for some elements on their sites. This may result in you blocking the element on one page, but not on any other page of the site. **The only option you have in this case is to find a common denominator and block that instead.** It is usually best to use the built-in developer tools for that to go through the page source.
>   [image]

How can I find that common denominator when open the dev tool? There is no meaningful result when googling `common denominator dev tool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common denominator isn't a specific thing, it is the upper level element which is common to a set of potentially randomly named lower elements

[Google search: define common denominator](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20common%20denominator)

> a feature shared by all members of a group.
>
> *"the common denominator in these companies is the awareness of the importance of quality"*

So work your way up the element tree until you find an element common to the items you want to block. It might be a specially named DIV or some kind of placeholder.